# Solve $y^\prime-y=\sin x-\cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to solve the differential equation

$y^\prime-y=\sin x-\cos x$.

Comment: Try the step by step solution here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+-+y+%3D+sin+x+-+cos+x

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular solution is

$$y_p=-\sin x$$

The homogeneous solution is

$$y_h=Ae^x$$

So the general solution is

$$y=Ae^x-\sin x$$